# How to define the alias with all the files including hidden files, list numbering, total lines in Linux?

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, alias, kali-linux

I have written a command but it displays only the total lines. I want total lines with numbering and their name. If I remove wc -l it only shows the numbering with their name. I want all this command to be execute at ones.

alias abc='ls -a | nl | wc -l'

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "total lines with numbering and their name"  ... can you edit your post and add some (mockup?) sample output?

Comment: You can use a temp file, e.g. `alias abc='ls -al | tee /tmp/tmpdl | nl; wc -l < /tmp/tmpdl && rm /tmp/tmpdl'`. Not pretty, but it works `:)` Though with `nl` outputting the total number for the last line -- it is unclear why you want the `wc -l` output as well -- but it is doable.

Answer (score 0):

Awk is another option for this:

```
alias abc="ls -a | awk '{ printf cnt++\"\t\"\$0\"\n\" } END { print cnt }'"
```

Pipe ls -a to awk and increment a count. Print count along with each line of output and then at the end, print cnt on a separate line.

Comment: Though generally probably recommend preferring a function over an alias.